# MotionLayout header expanded on first swipeUp

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

In my case I have a motionLayout containing a header and a recyclerView as anchor, the header is supposed to collapse at the first down swipe, and expanded when the last possible swipe up happens (position 0 in the recycler view).
The default behaviour is expanding the header when the first swipe up happens.
Is there a flag or an attribute that allows me to alter this behaviour?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

moveWhenScrollAtTop="true|false"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems the problem is having a SwipeRefreshLayout as anchor, I tried this property with a NestedScrollView and it worked, doesn't seem to be the case with a SwipeRefreshLayout